# How do I design a DB Table when my sources are VENN DIAGRAMS?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Imagine 3 circles. Each circle has some numbers

Circle 1 has the following numbers

1, 4, 7, 9

Circle 2 has the following numbers

2, 5, 8, 9

Circle 3 has the following numbers

3, 6, 7, 8, 9

Circle 1 and Circle 2 share the following numbers

10, 9

Circle 1 and Circle 3 share the following numbers

7, 9

Circle 2 and Circle 3 share the following numbers

8, 9

All three circles share

9

Each number represents symptoms so in my case

Circle 1's numbers could be symptoms for a short circuit
Circle 2 could be numbers for a component failure
Circle 3 could be numbers for external issues

each of the three issues share certain symptoms

If given #9, we wouldn't be able to deduce the problem but could display a list of all issues involving #9

If given more #'s, we can attempt to show relevant issues.

My problem is how do I put this into a table so my code can look things up.

My Database of choice is SQLite3

@Vincent, the only issue I have is that there are several variables. I have variables called t1, t2, t3, a1, a2, a3. Each of these variables are symptoms. The user interface for my application allows the user to input a value for each variable then I want to check the DB. All values for each symptom can be any value in the 3 circles (mentioned in original problem)

Comment: Are these circles pictures, or specified as a point and a radius with a set of what they contain? How do you actually describe these circles?

Comment: Keep in mind that Venn Diagrams are simply visual representations of sets.  So, you would rarely want to design around the Venn Diagram, but rather the information that the diagram represents.

Comment: Are they visual? Is that part of the definition? I can represent a circle by drawing a picture of a circle, or specifying a point and a radius. One of these specifications would lead to a solution to this problem which is tractable, and another would require computer vision techniques. Are we talking about in general, or just for this example which has been provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 3 tables as:

```
symptom = (symptom_id, descr)
problem = (problem_id, descr)
problem_symptom = (problem_id, symptom_id)
```

e.g.

```
Symptom
Symptom_id    Desc
1             doda
2             dado
3             dada

Problem
Problem_id    Descr
1             Short Circuit
2             Component Failure

Symptom_Problem
Symptom_id    Problem_id
1             1            --- doda is a symptom of Short circuit
2             1            --- dado is a symptom of short circuit
```

etc.

You can then query and join to determine the problems based on the symptoms.

Comment: It should also be noted that this answer doesn't limit itself to the rather simple constraints of a Venn Diagram... i.e. it scales quite a bit better than Venn Diagrams tend to (especially with regards to the number of sets, or in this case the number of problems).

Comment: the only issue I have is that there are several variables. I have variables called t1, t2, t3, a1, a2, a3. Each of these variables are symptoms. The user interface for my application allows the user to input a value for each variable then I want to check the DB. All values for each symptom can be any value in the 3 circles (mentioned in original problem)

Comment: @Cocoa Dev So each variable corresponds to a symptom. You then want to create a query that joins the 3 tales and restricts the results based on the provided symptoms. Then you can display a list of potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 tables: symptom, problem, and problem_symptoms. The latter would be a join table between the first two.

Comment: could you give me a sample SQL query of what it would look like?

Comment: select * from problem p inner join problem_symptom ps on p.problem_id = ps.symptom_id inner join symptom s on ps.symptom_id = s.symptom_id;

Comment: You could add an if clause to the above query to limit the rows, or do something like: select distinct p.* from problem p inner join problem_symptom ps on p.problem_id = ps.symptom_id inner join symptom s on ps.symptom_id = s.symptom_id where s.symptom_id in (1,2,3,4);